# Replace image, video sizes in HTML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have many videos and photos with size of width: 600px but different heights in a WordPress blog. How can I replace them using JQuery to scale? The videos are in

Here's an example of the code:

```
<img height="100" width="600" alt="image title" src="image link">
<embed width="600" ...>
<iframe width="600" ...>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img, embed, iframe').attr('width',newWidth);
```

- edit after your comment

Ofcourse there is:

```
$('img, embed, iframe').each(function() {
    if($(this).width() > 520) {
        $(this).attr('width','520');
        $(this).attr('height','auto');
    }
});
```

The selector `$('img, embed, iframe')` selects all the elements matching to our criteria. They have to be either an img, an embed, or an iframe. `.each(function(){...});` means that for all of these matches, we're going to do the code located within the brackets. What we do there, is check if the current object `$(this)` has a width greater than 520px (the function returns only 520, without px). If so, the code between the brackets is executed. We just change the attribute `width` from whatever it is (greater than 520px obviously) to 520px. That's it, basic jQuery. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Much thanks, rsplak. I am almost there. Is there anyway to proportionally resize images (width with the height? I would like to find the images on the page and then if their width are 600px, I will resize the images to scale keeping their new width of 520px. But if the images have less than 520px (my page width), no change is required. Same thing, I want to apply for the embed/iframe.

Comment: Thanks, rsplak. This precisely solves my problem. Well, will come back to you if something come up along the way. Much thanks.

Comment: Hey rsplak. Thanks for making this easier. Is there anyway to have a simple calculation to assign the height rather than using auto for images. 'auto' seems not to work on some cases. I was thinking of y=520xz/600 to set the proportion of the height where z=original height and y=the new height. What do you think?

Comment: In the meantime, I substituted .attr( with .css('height','auto') and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you rather use CSS ?

```
$('img, embed, iframe').css('width',newWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a good jquery plugin that will make your job easier -> http://plugins.jquery.com/project/imgscale